# Legend being cut off on saving - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, legend

I'm plot multiple subplots using this code:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(7, 1, sharex='col', figsize=(13, 20))

for i in range(simulations):
    delta = numpy.zeros((simulations+samples, simulations+samples))
    data_x = ensamble_x + sample_x[i*100:(i*100)+100] 
    data_y = ensamble_y + sample_y[i*100:(i*100)+100] 
    for j in range(simulations+samples):
        for k in range(simulations+samples):
            if j <= k:
                dist = similarity_measure((data_x[j].flatten(), data_y[j].flatten()), (data_x[k].flatten(), data_y[k].flatten()))
                #delta[j, k] = delta[k, j] = numpy.mean(dist)

    model = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
    coords = model.fit_transform(delta)

    axes[i].scatter(coords[:100, 0], coords[:100, 1], marker='x', c=colors[i], s=50, edgecolor='None')
    axes[i].scatter(coords[100:, 0], coords[100:, 1], marker='o', c=colors, s=50, edgecolor='None')

    axes[i].set_title('Simulation '+str(i+1))

markers = []
labels = [str(n+1) for n in range(simulations)]
for i in range(simulations):
     markers.append(Line2D([0], [0], linestyle='None', marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="none", markerfacecolor=colors[i]))
plt.legend(markers, labels, numpoints=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, -0.055), ncol=simulations) 
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Simulations.pdf', format='pdf')
```

Which generates something like this:

[image]

However, the saved `pdf` is cutting off half of the legend. I've tried to change the `figsize` parameter, but it didn't work.

How do I force the inclusion of the legend on the saved plot?

I've tried to use:

```
markers = []
labels = [str(n+1) for n in range(simulations)]
for i in range(simulations):
     markers.append(Line2D([0], [0], linestyle='None', marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="none", markerfacecolor=colors[i]))
lgd = plt.legend(markers, labels, numpoints=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, -0.055), ncol=simulations) 
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Simulations.pdf', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), format='pdf')
```

With no success too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me was this:

```
plt.savefig(file_path + '.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

I.e, I had to insert `bbox_inches='tight'` in the `savefig` options.

Answer (score 1):

try adding some extra space below your subplots using:

```
f.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
```

(adjust the `0.2` to suit your needs)